# Using autocomplete on a form not in DOM

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Let me begin by saying that I'm on JQuery version 1.3.2. Upgrading at this point is not an option.

I have a form that is added in by a templating system *after* the page load occurs. I'm very new to JQuery but it's my understanding that `live` will allow me to access it.

The function for the autocomplete already serves a user search and works well. I want to share this function for the admin part of the site as well as the query is almost identically the same.

The `clientName` element is from the dynamically added form. If I use the code below, nothing happens; no data is retrieved.

```
  $('#clientName')
  .site_clientAutocomplete(
    'admin',
    function( $event, $result, $data )
    {
      $('#clientName').val($data.ClientName);
    }
  );
```

If I wrap it inside the following code, it will work, sort of. I have to click inside the input box several times before I can get anything back from the database.

```
$("#clientName").live('keydown', function(){

});
```

Can someone tell me how I can get this autocomplete to function properly?

Comment: `live` works for event handlers only. it doesn't detect changes to the DOM and allow you to react to them. You could look at the "livequery" plugin, or you could apply the widget when the new content has been loaded into the DOM.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, thank you Andrew. I'll have a look at the plugin now

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, I'm looking at that library now and it seems like it may work for me. Can you tell me what event handler I would use? I've looked through the docs but don't see one for autocomplete. Maybe keydown?

Comment: Check out the "API" section of the documentation on github. You could use `$('#clientName').livequery(function () { /* initialize autocomplete */ });` if I understand your use case correctly.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, Andrew, thank you. I just stumbled across it eleswhere and I have it working. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'd be happy to credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`live` is just for handling *events* that occur on elements matching the selector now or in the future. If you need more robust detection of elements matching your selector, you can either apply the widget when the content is added, or you can use the [livequery plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery)

With livequery, you can "listen" for new elements matching your selector and run a function when that event occurs. In your case, this would go something like this:

```
$('clientName').livequery(function () {
    $('#clientName').site_clientAutocomplete(
        'admin',
        function( $event, $result, $data )
        {
            $('#clientName').val($data.ClientName);
        }
   );
});
```